# Checking in with Ryanair - no longer possible for free more than 7 days ahead?

Tags: ryanair

I just checked into my flight on Ryanair. As you may know Ryanair is a cheap cheap cheap airline. It used to be that you could check in up to a month ahead and print your boarding pass (you must print it because otherwise they charge you to issue one at the airport).

It seems that now you cannot check in more than 7 days ahead unless you choose a paid seat.

Did I miss a step?

Comment: http://www.ryanair.com/en/need-to-know/online-checkin/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's absolutely right. It seems that Ryanair is very, very, VERY keen on selling you their seats - getting money off something that has no value whatsoever except that they will probably do their best to keep families apart who don't give in to their blackmail.

You are right. You can't checkin more than 7 days ahead with Ryanair flights. Which is especially great when you are staying away for eight or more days, since you cannot check in while you are at your computer at home.

Comment: There is a way around it btw... their website has a flaw